# Is there a non-recursive and uncountable language L?

Tags: formal-languages, uncountability

Does there exist a non-recursive language, L, such that the cardinality of L is uncountable?

I would really like an explanation as to why this question is true or false because at the moment, I have no idea. 
My understanding is that all recursive languages have to be countable since the set of all finite strings is countable. 
But I'm not sure if there is a non-recursive language which is uncountable.
Any help would be greatly appreciated,

Comment: Well, if there is any uncountable language it's clearly non-recursive, as you argue. So the question is, what definition of "language" do you assume?

Comment: Thanks for responding quickly,
The definition of language I am using is that it is a collection of words and each word is a finite string

Comment: I thought all languages over finite alphabet were countable... Aren't they?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Definition: a *word* over an alphabet $A$ is a finite sequence of elements of $A$.
Definition: a *language* over an alphabet $A$ is a set of words over $A$.

With these definitions, if $A$ is a finite set, then any language is countable (either finite, or countably infinite). This is because any language is a subset of the complete language $A^*$ (set of words over $A$).

Direct proof sketch: you can enumerate all the words in the language, in order of increasing length (and in lexicographic order for each given length, having defined an order of $A$). This process is well-defined because set of words of a given length is finite. This process assigns an index to all the words in the language because all words have a finite length.

Follow-up exercise: if $A$ is countably infinite then a language over $A$ is countable. Adapt the proof above (change the enumeration order to cover the whole language in finite batches).

Comment: Ah thank you, so there are no non-recursive languages that are uncountable. Your proof about enumerating the words in the language in order of increasing length makes sense and solidifies this claim.

Answer (score 2):

Per your comment, you say a language is a collection of words of finite length. So you can encode each word as a natural number (for example interpret is as an integer in base size-of-your-alphabet). As you've just assigned a number to each element of your set, your set is countable.