# Is L={<M>|M is a TM and L(M) is uncountable} decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, computability, undecidability, rice-theorem, uncountability

Is $L=\{\langle M\rangle\mid \text{$M$ is a Turing machine and $L(M)$ is uncountable}\}$ decidable?

My intuition is that it is not, but I'm not sure if Rice's Theorem applies in this case. If it is not decidable, how can I prove that using reducibility?

Answer (score 10):

This is somewhat of a trick question. What you are missing is that [there are no uncountable languages over a finite (or even countable) alphabet](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/55851/is-there-a-non-recursive-and-uncountable-language-l?rq=1). This should be enough information to answer it.

(I initially gave the entire answer away, but edited it out after considering a bit.)